# Object folding in on itself

Tags: modeling

I am working on a bedroom project in Blender while following a tutorial. I'm not sure what I did wrong, but while attempting to color the walls of my bedroom, I realized some of the parts were- folding in on themselves?

I'm not sure how this happened, I recently merged the vertices by distance to fix a different issue; would that have anything to do with it?

Here is the blend file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/OsmXJW7G

I feel a bit silly asking another question only minutes after my last got resolved. I'm just not sure what else to do.

Help and advice very appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Hello, for the moment you still have overlapping vertices, so you need to Merge by Distance, and also you have a Bevel modifier, which creates bevels, but I'm not sure what you mean by "folding parts" (but I can't select these half faces like you show)

Comment: I think I figured it out! I removed the Bevel modified then re-added it, but instead I set it to "by vertices" rather than "edges". Thank you for the help!

Comment: oh ok yes it's the Bevel modifier that created this effect for some reason

Comment: Well, are you sure you want to bevel the vertices? What was the problem with the edge bevels?

Answer (score 3):

1. check your face orientation and repair it -> if you click on "overlays" -> check "face orientation": red means: wrong orientation.

To repair, select red object, TAB -> edit mode -> A (select all) -> Shift N

if all is blue...

2. delete double faces -> select object, TAB -> edit mode -> A (select all) -> M -> merge by distance

after that your problems should be gone.

Answer (score 2):

You have internal faces which is considered [non manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry) and messes up the Bevel Modifier causing your distorted geometry.

[image]

And don't forget this side as well. Once you have deleted these internal faces, your Bevel Modifier will work perfectly :)

[image]

Comment: +1 This probably happened because you Extruded > Changed your mind > right-click canceled the move (Leaving the extruded geo in place) > Decided to inset > Inset the now doubled face you had selected. Remember that when you press E to extrude you are actually doing two things at once: Extruding the geo and then moving it. When you right-click to cancel you only cancel the move part. Be aware of that.